# Installing VMwarePlayer on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation

I get a Error "one or more of your processors does not have the necessary 64 bit extensions to run Vware Virtual Machines" What does this mean?
My sys 32-bit, Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, VMware 5.0.1 32-bit. 
After typing in the consol "gksudo bash ./VMware-Player-5.0.1-894247.i386.bundle  press enter. extracting VMware Installer...done. Then i get the error message.

Comment: Please check your BIOS System settings for an option about Virtualization Technology (VT) or alike. It has to be enabled to run 64-bit virtual machines in a environment. Besides that, I think it's not an *error*, but a *warning*.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable virtualization in your BIOS (when you boot your computer press F2 or DEL usually).

This will allow VMWare, or any other virtualization program (Virtualbox, KVM, XEN, ...) to access your processor directly.
Make sure your CPU actually supports virtualization.
I have an atom, and those do not support virtualization for example.
On the other hand I have an AMD bulldozer, and those support virtualization, but by default it's disabled in the bios.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe don't have virtualization on your computer. Check in your bios would be the best way to know than try to fix the error know. I installed VMware and it gave me tons of errors and wasn't easy to fix. Try uninstalling VMware and first check your bios to see if you have virtualization on your computer than going though errors like me.

Answer (score -3):

Ahh, i see the problem. You're not running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu. You also don't have a 64-bit chipset, so that's probably why. I would recommend getting a 64-bit capable motherboard and also a 64-bit chipset.

Just a tip: The chipset should be an Intel chipset. And I would also recommend getting a 64-bit CPU as well.

I would recommend using Intel as they've been around for awhile and they know their stuff, and Ubuntu supports Intel most.

Comment: But how does *Ubuntu* support Intel more than it supports AMD?

Comment: Because Intel has been around longer, duh. And anyway, like I said, AMD sucks...

Comment: Being around longer *or being better overall* does not mean it is *more or better supported by Ubuntu*.

Comment: This answer and the comments of the answerer are completely unrelated to the issue and "nonsense" in my opinion. Both Intel and AMD have similar technology in virtualization - but that is way off topic to discuss here.